# How to check channel permissions?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

You can lock channel but if someone executes the command again how to send a message back that channel is already locked.

```
if (command === "lock") {
  await message.channel.overwritePermissions(message.guild.defaultRole, {
    SEND_MESSAGES: false
  });
  return message.channel.send(`:lock: The channel is now locked..\nUse \`k!unlock\` to end lockdown.. `);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`TextChannel.permissionOverwrites`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=permissionOverwrites), a Collection with every overwrite:

```
let {id} = message.guild.defaultRole, // get the ID of defaultRole
  ow = message.channel.permissionOverwrites.get(id); // get the permissionOverwrites fro that role

// If the overwrites exist and SEND_MESSAGES is set to false, then it's already locked
if (ow && ow.SEND_MESSAGES === false) message.channel.send("The channel is already locked.");
else { // otherwise, lock it
  await message.channel.overwritePermissions(message.guild.defaultRole, { SEND_MESSAGES: false }, );
  return message.channel.send(`:lock: The channel is now locked..\nUse \`k!unlock\` to end lockdown.. `);
}
```